# Windows 11 Pro still on 22H2 while latest updates enabled

Tags: windows-11, windows-update

I have my laptop set to get the latest updates when available. This setting has been on for months now. Still, I'm on 22H2. I can click the update button repeatedly and then it says the system is up to date.

**Why can't Windows update properly?**

[image: Windows Update]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I safely update Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1526972/can-i-safely-update-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(If you are not receiving the Windows 23H2 update and are stuck on Windows 11 22H2)*

***KB5027397: Feature update to Windows 11, version 23H2 enablement package***

*Windows 11, versions 22H2* and *23H2* share a common core operating system with an identical set of system files. The new features are in dormant and will remain dormant until they are turned on through the “[enablement package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5027397-feature-update-to-windows-11-version-23h2-by-using-an-enablement-package-b9e76726-3c94-40de-b40b-99decba3db9d#:%7E:text=The%20enablement%20package%20is%20a,advantage%20of%20new%20features%20now.)”, a small, quick-to-install “master switch” that activates the *Windows 11, version 23H2* features.

- While Microsoft says it is not available in the *Microsoft Update Catalog*, you can find it [here](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/kb5027397-enablement-package-for-windows-11-version-23h2-feature-update.19372/):

[image]

**Prerequisites:** Before updating to *Windows 11, version 23H2* using an enablement package

1. You must be running *Windows 11, version 22H2*.
2. You must have the following prerequisite installed before applying this [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-31-2023-kb5031455-os-builds-22621-2506-and-22631-2506-preview-6513c5ec-c5a2-4aaf-97f5-44c13d29e0d4) or a later cumulative update:

> October 31, 2023—KB5031455 (OS Builds 22621.2506 and 22631.2506) Preview

***You must restart your device after you apply this update.***

Answer (score 2):

As of October 11 2023, this remains normal.

The 3 ways to try to get to 23H2 are:

1. Enable "Get Latest Update ...." in Windows 11 Update.
2. Download and run Microsoft Update Assistant.  I did - still shows 22H2.
3. Download the latest Windows 11 from the Media Creation Link.  I did - still shows 22H2.

So you can do is wait for a bit and Microsoft will start rolling out soon.

For the most of us, not today (October 11, 2023)

Microsoft introduced a concept called Enablement about a year ago.  Make sure Enablement is running on your computer. You need Enablement for early adoption of Feature Updates. If installed or you install it, it will keep up to date.

[Enablement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5015684-featured-update-to-windows-10-version-22h2-by-using-an-enablement-package-09d43632-f438-47b5-985e-d6fd704eee61)

> Windows 10, versions 2004, 20H2, 21H1, 21H2, and 22H2 share a common
> core operating system with an identical set of system files.
> Therefore, the new features in Windows 10, version 22H2 are included
> in the latest monthly quality update for Windows 10, version 2004,
> 20H2, 21H1, and 21H2 but are in an inactive and dormant state. These
> new features will remain dormant until they are turned on through the
> “enablement package,” a small, quick-to-install “master switch” that
> activates the Windows 10, version 22H2 features

They (Microsoft) have announced starting around now, but it will take some time.

[Windows 11 23H2](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/install-windows-11-22h3-update/?utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=e064_10.11.23&utm_term=microsoft-active-weekly)

**Follow up:  November 7 2023.**

Windows 11 23H2 is now out. All 3 of my Lenovo (commercial) machines updated today. One new laptop. Other Desktop and Laptop new in early 2022.

Microsoft still evaluates where given machines will accept the update.

Comment: Windows 11 23H2 is now out @SPRBRN

Comment: I checked 9 hours ago, and it wasn't.  Thanks for that bleeding edge tip, John.

Comment: @xofs , check my answer. You can update 23H2 manually.